# How to search an encrypted field in attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-encrypted

I have set up [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) in my app with individual 'iv's for every record.

```
# Fields
User.e_name
User.e_name_iv
```

I am trying to search the User table for a known name. I've tried:

```
User.find_by_name("Joe Bloggs") # undefined method "find_by_name" for Class
User.where("name = ?", "Joe Bloggs").first # column "name" does not exist
User.where(:e_name => User.encrypt_name("Joe Bloggs"))  # must specify an iv
```

How can I find a record by its name?

Comment: You'll have to weaken your encryption (use the same IV for all records, for example). When encrypting fields (passwords, etc.), you set up per-record iv/salt __precisely__ to disable any kind of mass queries.

Comment: The `:single_iv_and_salt` mode is deprecated and will be removed, though. So, I guess, your two choices are: don't encrypt or don't query.

Comment: An alternative is to filter in the application (this is obviously very slow and wastes a ton of resources)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well that's a pain. What do you think of storing a hash of the values in another column and comparing a search term to the hash (akin to logging in with a password)?

Comment: I'm no security expert, but this looks like a workable compromise.

Comment: This does weaken the security somewhat. But increases usability. Balancing the two is an art :)

Comment: @sscirrus You can't search by password when the password is hashed. Proper password hashing algorithms like BCrypt produce an output that contains a salt and a completely different hash, even with the same input password. This is analogous to your problem of each record having a different initialization vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to do some searching, it's not very practical. you'll have to potentially iterate through every record trying each respective IV until you have an exact match, depending on the number of records you have this will not be very practical.

Have you read the readme? https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted#things-to-consider-before-using-attr_encrypted

Searching, joining, etc

> While choosing to encrypt at the attribute level is the most secure
>   solution, it is not without drawbacks. Namely, you cannot search the
>   encrypted data, and because you can't search it, you can't index it
>   either. You also can't use joins on the encrypted data. Data that is
>   securely encrypted is effectively noise. So any operations that rely
>   on the data not being noise will not work. If you need to do any of
>   the aforementioned operations, please consider using database and file
>   system encryption along with transport encryption as it moves through
>   your stack.